# How can i save my django codes?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I just started downloaded django on my ubuntu, though I've bin developing with it on Windows; i just notice that i cant save all editing on settings.py; trying to change the database engine

```
>>>nano setting.py
>>>ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
```

I always get the error [ Error writing settings.py Permission denied ] How can i solve this? I'd really love to get help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Django problem. Check the permissions on the file:

```
$ ls -l settings.py
```

If needed, run one or both of the following:

```
$ sudo chmod 644 settings.py
$ sudo chown user.user settings.py
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval  $sudo chown user.user settings.py works